# How to use react-query without QueryClientProvider

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I'm unable to wrap my code with the `QueryClientProvider`.

Is that possible to configure the react-query in a different way? I can't modify anything inside any of the render functions.

Answer (score 1):

No, it’s not possible. React Query uses React context to distribute the QueryClient.